# How do I use Rangy

Tags: bower, amd, rangy

There's some information out there but I'm still very confused about how to use Rangy (https://github.com/timdown/rangy)

The demo on the git repository isn't working, nor did I find a good example of how to use it.

I have a simple html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="text.css">
<body>

<script>
require('rangy')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run the file, and get:
"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require"

I downloaded the file and tried to change the link in the require.
I also tried to just install it with node install, but can't quite seem to get it to work. Would love to get a few-line example of how to consume Rangy and use it.

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: `require` is when you are using a module system. You should be able to simply include the script as usual (script tag)

Comment: Thanks, that explains it!